# Get text from node excluding children

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to get the text from the node `<hello>`, excluding its children. I know that `/element/hello/text()` is supposed to work, but it doesn't.

```
<element>
  <hello><b>Exclude me</b> but not me <b>I'm excluded :(</b> I'm included</hello>
</element>
```

My output is only:`but not me` . If I remove the first node, everything works as it is supposed and the second text node (I'm included) is parsed. [Here](http://fiddle.frameless.io/), the native processor behaves similarly. Saxon works as expected. Might this be a bug? I'm using XML filters in LibreOffice 4.4.2.2.

Comment: /element/hello/text()[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the text from the node `<hello>`, excluding its
>   children. I know that `/element/hello/text()` is supposed to work, but
>   it doesn't.

`/element/hello/text()` does work to **select** the nodes you want.

However, if you're using `xsl:value-of` to get the text, it will only return the value from the **first** node of the selected set. To get all of them, you must do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/element/hello/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

The above applies to XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:value-of select="/element/hello/text()"/>
```

will return the text of **all** selected nodes, separated by a space (unless you specify a different separator).